# I am really struggling to push some information from a form onto a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

I am trying to add some information as a string to an array nested in an object. I am trying to use a very simple form to do this, using the e.target.elements.inputName.value as the data for the string.

However, when i send the form to update the landmarks property I am getting undefined back in the console. This undefined is replacing what I could previously see in the console, namely my one city object (I have an array of cities that are objects, on which I have a landmarks array.)

I can push the new city object to my cities array no problem, with the landmarks property set to an empty array, but when I try to add a landmark in using a form and the push method, city.landmarks.push(landmarkValue) my code is breaking and I am getting undefined.

This is the code for my index.js

```
let cities = getSavedCities()


const cityDiv = document.querySelector('#cities')

renderCities()



document.querySelector('#add-city').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    cityDiv.innerHTML = ''
    const id = uuidv4()
    cities.push({
        id: id,
        name: e.target.elements.addCity.value,
        country: '',
        landmarks: []
    })
    saveCities()
    renderCities()
    

    e.target.elements.addCity.value = ''
    
})
```

This is the code for my edit.js, where I am trying to add the landmark

```
const cityId = location.hash.substring(1)
const cities = getSavedCities()
const city = cities.find((city) => city.id === cityId)
const nameH2 = document.querySelector('#city-name')
const home = document.querySelector('#home')

nameH2.textContent = city.name



document.querySelector('#landmarks').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const city = cities.find((city) => city.id === cityId)
    const landmark = e.target.elements.landmarks.value
    city.landmarks.push(landmark)
    saveCities()
    e.target.elements.landmarks.value = ''
    
})
```

Once I submit the form, my saved city object that I generated is being replaced with undefined and I am getting the following error message.

```
VM201:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getSavedCities (functions.js:5:21)
    at edit.js:2:16
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error inside **getSavedCities()** function, you must check if the value is undefined before parsing it.
You cannot parse a JSON with an undefined value.
A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering, I don't understand why the value would be undefined. I can see my city object saved in local storage, then when I try to push on the landmark property I get undefined, but I don't understand why.

Comment: I have found the solution, thanks again for helping.